# Does navigation.goBack() work in a child component when a parent component uses withNavigation?

Tags: react-native

Code of a child component is like this

```js
export default class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: props.navigation.state.params.items,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text>GO BACK</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Nothing happens when I press GO BACK. What's wrong with this?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this :)

Comment: only if
1. the component is a direct descendant of a router
2. it is wrapped in withNavigation
3. the navigation prop was passed to it from the parent component

Comment: Okay thanks. So, should I wrap this child component in withNavigation?

Comment: either that or pass the navigation prop to them: <Child navigation={this.props.navigation} />